# Where should i define all my view objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, viewdidload

Ok, so till now i have been declaring all my view objects in .h file. For e.g:

```
 UIButton *btnCustomFacebookLogin;
```

And define in my .m file like:

```
btnCustomFacebookLogin = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnCustomFacebookLogin.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
btnCustomFacebookLogin.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,180,40);
btnCustomFacebookLogin.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 200);
[btnCustomFacebookLogin setTitle: @"Facebook Login" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[btnCustomFacebookLogin addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookLoginButtonClicked) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btnCustomFacebookLogin];
```

And i have a few more buttons in my app which are all defined in my

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

I got this checked from my mentor and he told me that all these buttons should be in a separate method and not in viewDidLoad, i have no idea where they should be, i went through some sample codes on the internet and could not find a clue. What is the proper place where all the buttons are defined ? Since i work for a company now i have to follow what conventions are told to me.

Comment: You could create a method namely, `-(void)createAllButtons` and put all your button creation code in that. Then from `viewDidLoad` you could call `createAllButtons` method.

Comment: You can declare in .h file.

Comment: Why aren't you framing those buttons in .storyboard file ? Or in .xib ?

Comment: @Hima - That is how i was told to do it. Can't help.

Comment: So every implementation file that includes that header gets their own reference to a `UIButton`?  This is completely the wrong way to do things.

Comment: @nikhil84 - Since you are a ios developer, is this how it is supposed to be ?

Comment: No, it is not how it is supposed to be.

Comment: @trojanfoe - What is the correct way, sorry i am totally new to ios development and have been doing things on my own.

Comment: why don't you declare in .h file ?

Comment: You need to follow one of the many tutorials out there.  Throw away what you currently have and delete this question.

Comment: Approach depends upon the requirement. If you need to create multiple buttons programmatically then you need to modularise the code for button creation and call that method whenever needed. On other side, if you dont need to do programmatically then go for storyboard and add button there (use constraints and set UI of button) and for action add IBAction method and connect with UIButton.

Comment: @trojanfoe - Why delete the question, it will surely help someone else later.

Comment: Agree with @trojanfoe that you need to first go for some tutorial for understanding the objective c.

Comment: @TejasK Not at all.  You won't get an answer as it's too broad.

Comment: @trojanfoe - But i got my answer from nikhil's comment. And i have been going through tutorials, but all of them had the code in viewDidLoad, and i think such questions can only be answered by someone who is a developer himself, not by any tutorial.

Comment: Are you sure your mentor said the button references should go into separate methods and not as instance variables or properties?

Comment: All the tutorials on the internet give you the idea how to accomplish your task, they maybe working, but not well formatted, and when you are ready to write something yourself all of a sudden you start modifying those tutorial internet codes, and change it to the better format. Perhaps, your mentor wants you to have a better format.

Comment: @trojanfoe - Yes, and i have been doing things how i mentioned in the question, and now i was told this isn't the correct way. Strange.

Comment: @FahriAzimov - Yes, i was told to make my code follow all the conventions, i went through ray wenderlich's guide, but this was mentioned no where.

Comment: @TejasK, it seems you need to change your mentor first as soon as possible – whatever you are trying to do here it is completely wrong.

Comment: @holex - I can't, i know the way things are going is not correct, and the learning process is totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `IBOutlets` properties outside of header file (*.h) and declare them inside implementation file (*.m) in interface extension of your View Controller.

In your implementation file (*.m) :

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
@end
```

Remember to set your property behaviour `nonatomic` as by default each property gets `atomic` behaviour and when using UI objects there is no need to make them thread safe. Set it to `weak`as you are not a direct owner of the object, its lifecycle belongs to your storyboard (assuming you use storyboard).

[Meet Doshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3908884/meet-doshi) is correct about using `viewDidLoad` and performing selector from inside it, to make an initial setup for your UI elements. It makes your code clear and readable.

I would possibly call it:

```
- (void)styleUI {
   //insert your code here
}
```

If you find yourself to set specific UIButton styling in different View Controllers in this same way, then to avoid boilerplate code you could create own Class Category for `UIButton` and specify this same style in one place.

- Create a new file selecting **Objective-C File**.
- In File type prefix for your project with name for class (example:
  **MAPStyling**).
- Select **Category** for File Type.
- Select **Class** that you want to create a category for (for `UIButton` select `UIButton`).

Inside you category class in implementation file (*.m) add method for your styling:

```
- (void)map_applyFacebookStyle
   // insert your code here but instead to name of your button refer to self.
   self.title = @"Facebook Login";
}
```

Expose method in header file of your category by adding method signature into `@interface` section.

```
@interface UIButton (MAPStylig)
- (void)map_applyFacebookStyle;
@end
```

In your View Controller implementation file (*.m) import your Class Category and modify your method:

```
- (void)styleUI {
  [btnCustomFacebookLogin map_applyFacebookStyle];
}
```

This will call `@selector` of your styling method from your Class Category on your `UIButton`. As you can imagine in this way you can remove a lot of boilerplate code from every View Controller in your application.

Comment: Worth noting you should start a method name with a lowercase letter

Comment: Correct, wanted to expose need for prefix. Thanks for letting me know mate.

Answer (score -1):

Your mentor says, "All these buttons should be in a separate method and not in viewDidLoad". Means you are setting frames and properties to all buttons into viewDidLoad method. He didn't said that you can't define all objects into .h file. So he says, you have do that into other method. Just use following code.

I think, right now you did this:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    btnCustomFacebookLogin = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnCustomFacebookLogin.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    btnCustomFacebookLogin.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,180,40);
    btnCustomFacebookLogin.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 200);
    [btnCustomFacebookLogin setTitle: @"Facebook Login" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnCustomFacebookLogin addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookLoginButtonClicked) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btnCustomFacebookLogin];
}
```

So, just put this code into one method and call this method from viewDidLoad like this:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self settingPropertiesOfButtons];
} 

- (void)settingPropertiesOfButtons
{
    //insert your code here..
    btnCustomFacebookLogin = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnCustomFacebookLogin.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    btnCustomFacebookLogin.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,180,40);
    btnCustomFacebookLogin.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 200);
    [btnCustomFacebookLogin setTitle: @"Facebook Login" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnCustomFacebookLogin addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookLoginButtonClicked) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btnCustomFacebookLogin];
}
```

That's it. If you could framing those buttons in .storyboard file or in .xib, then its better.

Comment: Show the declaration of `btnCustomFacebookLogin`.